# I am trolling on roblox a gaming platform with gifs and i need to decrypt this script to lua 5.1.4

Tags: lua, roblox

The script is at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/1tyre/my-pile-of-stuff/main/lua/tyresbucketstealer.lua if you click this it should pull of a raw of the script i need to be decrypted

Comment: punctuation-only strings look interesting

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a request for a coding service.

Answer (score 1):

You can't "decrypt" it. This code is specially designed to NOT be readable, its called obfuscation.

Answer (score 0):

Man, you can't really deobfuscate code. It is an extremely hard thing to do no matter which language is used. Maybe figure out more about Lua before trying to use a crappy roblox script.